# Is there a convenient function in objective-c / cocoa-touch to find a lowest number?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two numbers, and need to get returned the lower one. Is there any function I could use? Sure it's a easy task, I could do an if-statement. I just want to know.

Comment: retagged as not being specific to objective-C or UIKit

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you're using ints, use the `MIN()` macro:

```
MIN(25, 50); //Returns 25
```

If you're comparing two `NSNumber`s, then use the `compare:` method:

```
NSNumber *number, *secondNumber; //Assume 'number'=25, 'secondNumber'=50
NSComparisonResult result = [number compare:secondNumber];

return (result==NSOrderedDescending)?secondNumber:number; //Returns the 'number' NSNumber
```

Answer (score 56):

The C standard library includes several `min()` functions that, given two numbers, will return the lower of the two:

```
 double fmin(double x, double y);
 long double fminl(long double x, long double y);
 float fminf(float x, float y);
```

To use these, just `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: These are for floating point numbers. Are there similar stdlib functions for integers?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg, in C99 the macro [`fmin( x, y )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmin) works for `int`.

Answer (score 11):

For minimum no. use

```
MIN(number1,number2);
```

For maximum no. use

```
MAX(number1,number2);
```

Comment: Note this works with ints, no NSNumbers. For NSNumber use `@(MIN(nsNumber1.intValue, nsNumber2.intValue))`