# predefined function for minimum

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a convenient function in objective-c / coca-touch to find a lowest number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844990/is-there-a-convenient-function-in-objective-c-coca-touch-to-find-a-lowest-numbe)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int a=10,b=5,c;
    c=min(a,b);
    NSLog(@"min:%d",c);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

I have to calculate the minimum value of two numbers.
We can use if(a>b) to find out the minimum value.But is there any predefined function to calculate the minimum of two numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125126/how-would-you-define-a-simple-min-method-in-obj-c exact duplicate

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844990/ and read the answer about `math.h`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There was already a discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125126/how-would-you-define-a-simple-min-method-in-obj-c). Objective-C includes a MIN(a,b) macro, which should suit your needs.