# Math.min in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can any one tell me how can change this java code into objective c.is there any function for
Math.min. i'm new to objective c

```
result = Math.min(Math.min((hra * 12), rent), 
    (0.4 * pay));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a convenient function in objective-c / coca-touch to find a lowest number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844990/is-there-a-convenient-function-in-objective-c-coca-touch-to-find-a-lowest-numb)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `MIN` from `NSObjCRuntime.h`:

```
#ifndef MIN
#import <NSObjCRuntime.h>
#endif

result = MIN(MIN((hra * 12), rent), (0.4 * pay));
```

Comment: MIN(A,B) is already defined in NSObjCRuntime.h - no need for extra imports or redefinitions.

Comment: NSObjCRuntime.h is imported as part of Foundation.h. So there is no need for the check or the import. Just use it.

Comment: I can see you are trying to justify yourself. but the iPhone tag is a bit of a give away. That means Cocoa. Find me a Cocoa app that doesn't use Foundation.h. So NSObjcRuntime.h is already imported, so there is no need to check for the macro definition and to import the header again. If MIN was already defined elsewhere it would conflict with the definition in NSObjCRuntime.h, which is already included, so this wouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Abizern: The fact that an application uses Foundation does not imply that every compilation module includes the header.  It's entirely possible that the module in question might require an additional `#import`.

Comment: All I'm trying to say is that you don't need to define MIN (which was done in the original answer that was quickly edited away), nor do you need to have the first three lines. Just use MIN(…) All the rest of it just seems to be, IMO, justification for leaving those three lines. Foundation is imported in the pch by Xcode, and I doubt the OP edits that. Yes it's entirely possible that foundation isn't imported, but highly unlikely. As for the paranoid checks against redefinition, really?

Answer (score 11):

You can use math.h from C :

```
#import <math.h>

// double fmin (double, double)
NSLog(@"res: %.f", fmin(5,10));
```